# Non-iterable argument to a function called by Julia `map`?

Tags: julia

I have a `for` loop that has to call the `map` function whose function `f` uses an element of a vector and a scalar to perform a simple multiplication. I want the scalar to be the value of the loop variable at each iteration. How can I do this in Julia without re-declaring the function at each iteration of the loop? E.g.,

```
some_vector = [1, 2, 3, 4]
n_indices = 5
for i in 1:n_indices
  function foo(ele)
    ele*i 
  end
  result = map(foo, some_vector)
  # other complicated logic ...
end
```

So I would like `foo` to be something like `foo(ele, i)` where `ele` is an element of an iterable and `i` is just a scalar. I know that I could just use an anonymous function in this case since the logic here is very simple, but `foo` is actually long and giving it a name is more expressive, so pulling `foo` out of the loop would be much more ideal if this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another method is to make the `for` variable an existing local variable using the `outer` keyword. The following code should be inside a function:

```
...
    local i::eltype(some_vector)
    foo2(ele) = ele*i
    for outer i in 1:n_indices
        result = map(foo2, some_vector)
        # other complicated logic ...
    end
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're working with a vector the idiomatic way would be to use [broadcasting](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/#Broadcasting).

```
some_vector = [1, 2, 3, 4]
n_indices = 5

function foo(ele, i)
  ele*i 
end

for i in 1:n_indices
  result = foo.(some_vector, i)
  # other complicated logic ...
end
```